# Javascript timer used in points system

Tags: javascript, timer

I am trying to make a game. There are blocks falling and a main block which the user commands that is trying to avoid them. There is a point system that is supposed to add 10points each time the red cube touches one of the extremities. The problem is that it adds 10 points per each 10 milliseconds that the cube stays in the extremity. How can I solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a flag that you set and then clear whenever you touch the side.

Since the box starts touching the side, i initialized `already_touched` to true.

```
var already_touched = true;
```

Then your logic below becomes:

```
if (mySprite.x == 450 || mySprite.x == 0) {
    if (!already_touched) {
        already_touched = true;
        count += 10;
    } 
    var alert1 = document.getElementById("score");
    alert1.innerHTML = "Score: " + count;
} else {
    already_touched = false;
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/KrZq9/